# Why ALTERDB reports "No checkpoints available to delete" even though I have them on the filesystem?

Tags: sql

This morning I was greeted by **Ingres 10.0.0** with the following:

```
[ingres@denux ~]$ alterdb dejandb -keep=60
Mon May 28 08:54:17 2012 ALTERDB: No checkpoints available to delete.

[ingres@denux ~]$ ls -la /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/ckp/default/dejandb | wc -l
62
```

Checkpoints are obviously there. And Ingres nicely makes new checkpoints, but I can't delete them with `alterdb <dbname> -keep=<NN>`

Any ideas?

Note: This post should be tagged "ingres" but I have insufficient rank to create it. Need help here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all I needed was a strong coffee to wake me up!

Apparently `alterdb <database name> -keep=<NN>` will naturally work ONLY when there are NN checkpoints or more! :) I wanted to `-keep=60` but I had less than 60 because two weeks ago i did a cleanup, and left only 30...

So everything worked when I lowered the NN number...